# Is it correct to concatenate char to char array like that?

Tags: c

I was trying to concatenate char array with single char. I have seen some solutions but I saw also this one, and I'm not sure if it's correct.

```
void addCharacter( char* array, const char c )
{
    int asize = strlen( array );
    array[ asize ] = c;
    array[ asize+1 ] = '\0';
}


int main()
{
    char arrayd[13] = "Hello World!";
    printf("%s\n", arrayd);

    addCharacter(arrayd,'1');
    printf("%s\n", arrayd);
    return 0;
}
```

It compiles and looks well but should it be solved like that or allocate memory and create new array with bigger size?

Comment: I like that you are the OP and your name is quertyui. A nice sense of completeness.

Comment: All depends on what is passed in and how this is initialised.

Comment: And, BTW, `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the code that calls `addCharacter` including the corresponding variable declarations. The answer depends somewhat on that.

Comment: Everything is correct except the specific array is too short and doesn't have room for additional characters. Keep in mind that the null terminator needs to be stored too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine so long as `array` has at least `asize + 1 + 1` bytes allocated to it.

If not then the behaviour of the program will be undefined. In your case, the behaviour **is** undefined as `arrayd` is a 13 byte array.

Personally I'd like to see the length of `array` passed as a parameter to the function so you could check at the point of use.

You *could* build in `realloc` capabilities into the function, but then you'd need to pass `array` as a `char**` so you can modify the pointer and you'd need to concern yourself with the risk of consumers of the original pointer being invalidated.

Finally, passing NUL for `c` is essentially a no-op; I'd deal with that explicitly if I were you.